(Python/Pyside6) Exception ignored on threading shutdown
I get the following error:
Exception ignored on threading shutdown: 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Program Files\Python313\Lib\threading.py", line 1524, in _shutdown  
if _main_thread._handle.is_done() and _is_main_interpreter():
SystemError: <method 'is_done' of '_thread._ThreadHandle' objects> returned a result with an exception set    

When trying to run my App instance:
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui.ui import Ui_MainWindow 

class App(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication([])
window = App()
window.show()
app.exec() 

I've also attempted:
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = App()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())  

This has never happened to me before (as I'm sightly familiar with PySide6) and I wonder if has anything to do with styles applied to the ui or something.
You can also check the ui/ui.py here (Ui_MainWindow origin).  The qrc package is succesfully imported as ui/resources/package.py so that can't be either.
I'd like to know what can be the root of this SystemError.

What specific versions of Qt6 and PySide6 are you testing with? Does the exception only occur with that particular ui file? What happens if you remove the ui class and just show a plain QMainWindow? Does the exception occur when starting the script, when stopping it, or at some other time?

@ekhumoro Pyside6 Version: 6.8.0.2. Crashes when starting the script and only happens with this ui file. Other ui files run nicely, with icons, qrc packages and all. If I do not use a class, the same error shows. I've been working on this ui for a while and I want to understand what's causing it so I don't have to throw it away.

@ekhumoro Forget it, it was me placing an emoji on a label. Ok Pyside...

@user27827714 That shouldn't cause a crash, so it may be worth a report. Right now you didn't provide an appropriate [mre], so either you provide one (remember that questions should always be self-contained, and external resources are not accepted for source code), or you delete this, as it's currently not-reproducible (therefore, offtopic and scheduled for deletion anyway).

@musicamante Yeah, I'm reporting it. And I literally didn't know what was going on, how am I going to give an appropiate example? This community is exhausting. You guys do not know the meaning of "if it happened to you before (random thread issue) and you could give me an idea...". It was the "self.log.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\ud83d\udea8  ", None))". Crazy thing.

@user27827714 Well, you found out the cause of the problem, so a more appropriate MRE involves an extremely basic script that just calls the above and leaves out anything else. Reducing the problem to its bare cause is always the first thing to do, even when you end up with a problem you have never seen or you cannot sort out. For starters, you don't need a UI file to reproduce the problem: the issue is either in the translate() call, or in the setText() one: create a basic window with a label, separate those two calls and find out which one is the culprit.

@user27827714 In any case, it's possibly related to this issue. Python 3.12 shouldn't be affected by the problem, so you could downgrade to that version if you see that error again, otherwise wait for the 3.13.1 release (due in a few weeks).
